# how to go to column by its number in sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

How to go to row number `n` and column number `m` in `sublime text3`.

I  can go to row by number. But can't find out how to move to column by its number on this row.

I need it because I got error reportings with fileName and 2 numbers: for example: `24:13`. That means row `24` and column `13`.

So I need to move to row `24` and column `13` fast without counting how many times I clicked on right arrow on my keyboard.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just press `ctrl+p` (`cmd+p` on mac) to bring on "Goto Anything" palette, and then type colon, line number, colon, column number:

```
:24:13
```

You can also type filename first, and Sublime will move you straight to place in that file you need.

```
styles/main.css:24:13
```

Comment: That seems to only go to the row, not the column.

Comment: Good answer, but what if I just want to *see* what column number I'm on. Why can't/doesn't Sublime Text just show a little "Row: /Col: " indicator in the task bar at the bottom or something? That seems to me like a standard text editor feature I've always taken for granted.

Comment: @GabrielStaples [I had the same confusion as you!](https://superuser.com/a/1286363/112639) Sublime Text 3 *does* have a "Row: /Col: " indicator - but it's sometimes hidden, e.g. if you have the Find box open and it has results.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [GotoRowCol plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/GotoRowCol), which lets you specify a row and column to go to.

For this plugin to be useful, you should really consider making a custom keyboard shortcut to execute it – it's covered in the readme.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the shortcut `Ctrl`+`G` to open the jump to line dialog or by using the menu `Goto`->`Goto Line...`

I'm not aware of a jump-to-specific-column feature.

Comment: Actually you just have to add a colon followed by the column number to your input for Ctrl+G to got to a specific column. So to go to line 3 column 4 you just have to do Ctrl+G followed by entering 3:4 inside the dialogue box.