# How to see current column/character number of the cursor position in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Maybe I've missed something and/or am using the wrong search terms: this seems like a standard feature but I can't find any such option to show column numbers in the View menu and  can't find anything online beyond [that I can jump to, for example character #43 on line 9 with ctrl-p followed by `:9:43`](https://superuser.com/questions/636699/how-to-go-to-column-by-its-number-in-sublime-text-3). Which is nice, but how can I just see which column number the cursor is on?

I'd like to enable something in the status bar or somewhere else visible that shows what column number or character number my cursor is currently on. I'm sure I used to have this feature in Sublime Text 2, which I recently upgraded from.

At least one commenter in that linked question is having the same problem, so if I've missed something obvious, it's not just me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had missed something obvious! It turns out it *is enabled by default* - but **is hidden if the search bar is open and has matches** or if anything else is causing other information to be displayed in the bottom left corner. So, just remove whatever is putting info in the bottom left corner.

For example, here I can't see the column number:

[image]

...because it's replaced with information about my find box matches. Empty that, or close the box, and it's back:

[image]

Comment: Crucial to know where that went!

Comment: LOL! Good one @user568458.

Comment: 10k people seen this. Maybe someone should give them a hint that the GUI should be changed to always show line+column?

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Text top menu -> View -> hide / show status bar

[image: View Status Bar]

Comment: yes, I did read the accepted answer. regardless of search bar being open or close. you are not able to see column status bar if its hidden.

Comment: +1 this is a good additional answer in case, for example, someone searching on this had hidden the status bar by mistake